# hidePointsAtIndex hides tha xaxis labels too react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, expo

I use react-native-chart-kit expo https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit
When I use hidePointsAtIndex the yAxis labels are hidden too.
Can I avoid this behavior and display the xAxis labels?